# SQL CE 4 Patindex Not working

Tags: sql-server-ce

The patindex does not seem to work in SQL Server CE 4.0, I am sure there is a mistake somewhere from my part, as I can see examples elsewhere in the internet showing patingdex working in sql server ce .

When I execute the query

SELECT        PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'ABC123') AS Expr1
UNION ALL
SELECT        PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', '123456') AS Expr1

I get two rows with "0" value.

However if I run

SELECT        PATINDEX('%C%', 'ABC123') AS Expr1

I get "3" as the result. I can see that SQL CE 4.0 does not seem to recognise regular expressions.

please can someone help me!

PS: I use Visual Studio 2012 with SQL Server Ce 4.0

Thanks in Anticipation,

Arun

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any version of PATINDEX supporting regular expressions:
SQL Server Compact: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174069.aspx
SQL Server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx

Comment: Thank you Erik. But is there anyway by which I could filter only numeric columns?. I have a table column type nvarchar and would like to extract only the rows where the column value is numeric. Since ISNumeric is not available in CE, I was looking to use Patindex. Do you have any suggestions?. Thanks again!

Comment: You could possibly use a combination of PATINDEX, substring and datalength to filter out some rows, but you would stiil have to check in code via TryParse if the values were numeric